# Camera transition matrix - perspective

Tags: matrix

Let's suppose:

1) XY plane is perpendicular to the surface of the street given by an area between the two green lines and a normal to this plane has the same "direction" as the yellow line,

2) XY has only three degrees of freedom - moving along X, Y, Z (Z is X x Y),

3) a limit for an X- along translation is when P1 is coincident to P2.

How does the θ change while translating by an [x,y,z] vector? How would it change if I added a rotation along any of the given axes and got rid of the point 3) (6 degrees of freedom)? Can you give me any hint where to look for an answer?

Hope everything is clear!

[image: View of a street with lines indicated]